# Laravel, api, postman

Tags: laravel, api, controller

I am following a grafikart tutorial on the back-end of an API under laravel, but creating a comment module, and since yesterday I have this message why. I think that I come from a call or from a space name but I know ... on postman also it returns to me errors.

#### postman:

[image: postaman]

error message:
[image: error message]

[image: my controller]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages screenshots of code, errors & data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely, the question will be downvoted, for containing unnecessary screenshots.  By using screenshots, you are discouraging anyone from assisting you.  No one wants to retype your stuff, from a screenshot, and screenshots are often, not readable.

Answer (score 0):

Add the model namespace to your call, make sure you have a method called `allFor`

```
$comments = \App\Comment::allFor();
```

Comment: OP will get another error in the store method `Comment::isCommentable($model, $model_id);` it's better to import the class once rather than calling it via fully qualified name everytime

Comment: my calling : <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\Input;

Comment: my code in the function :     $comments = Comment::allFor(Input::get('commentable_type'), Input::get('commentable_id'));